# What BSD is the most friendly to a laptop?

Tags: laptop, bsd

Don't get me wrong here, I'm just probing opinions.
I'd like to try BSD on my laptop, to learn more, to have fun with:)
I'm currently choosing between NetBSD and OpenBSD, just a whim.
What I'm interested in is support and compatibility of mobile machines on BSD systems. I expect it to be worse than among linux guys for sure. How worse is it? What would you say about BSD on a laptop as a main os?

Comment: Still voting to close as not constructive. This is polling for a list of answers and not a good fit for the site as you can read in the [FAQ]. If you don't even say which laptop it is, you won't get a good answer, but only "I personally like …". Have you even tried to install one? Did you run into any problems?

Answer (score 5):

I've found FreeBSD to be easiest to run on a laptop. But its mostly a taste of preference and what needs you have, its very hard to reply to more than that I believe. :(

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Mattias (currently i use FreeBSD on a desktop pc and it works pretty well). 
But you can also check PC-BSD (based on FreeBSD) that is also more user friendly. 
You can check also that URL: http://www.pcbsd.org/pc-bsd/notebook